# Formik and Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, formik

I am trying to use Formik with Material-UI text field. Like so:

```
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import {
  Field,
  FieldProps,
  Form,
  Formik,
  FormikErrors,
  FormikProps
} from 'formik';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

interface IMyFormValues {
  firstName: string;
}

class CreateAgreementForm extends Component<{}> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>My Example</h1>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{ firstName: '' }}
          // tslint:disable-next-line:jsx-no-lambda
          onSubmit={(values: IMyFormValues) => alert(JSON.stringify(values))}
          // tslint:disable-next-line:jsx-no-lambda
          validate={(values: IMyFormValues) => {
            const errors: FormikErrors<IMyFormValues> = {};
            if (!values.firstName) {
              errors.firstName = 'Required';
            }
            return errors;
          }}
          // tslint:disable-next-line:jsx-no-lambda
          render={(formikBag: FormikProps<IMyFormValues>) => (
            <Form>
              <Field
                name="firstName"
                render={({ field, form }: FieldProps<IMyFormValues>) => (
                  <TextField
                    error={Boolean(
                      form.errors.firstName && form.touched.firstName
                    )}
                    helperText={
                      form.errors.firstName &&
                      form.touched.firstName &&
                      String(form.errors.firstName)
                    }
                  />
                )}
              />
            </Form>
          )}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CreateAgreementForm;
```

I want Formik to be responsible for validation and Material-UI for looks.
I want to pass errors.firstName to TextField component but the error doesn't display correctly. How can I fix it so it still will be clear to read? I don't want to write my own TextField component.

Comment: I don't know how to integrate Material-ui components with Formik validation, but i can recommend react-final-form instead which integrates very well with MUI : https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#material-ui-10

Comment: Thanks, but I still need to create my custom components for each of the material-ui components. I would rather not to. Do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: It may seem a little overkill but we found that actually simple and straight forward to wrap material-ui form components like this. I think you will always have to map the "FormXXX" framework props to the Material-UI components somehow.

Comment: You may take a look at what have been done in this project : https://github.com/stackworx/formik-material-ui/tree/master/src

Comment: I really think you should consider creating custom components for each Material-UI components. Here is why : do not repeat yourself (the mapping from Formik API to MUI props is done one time), limit the impact of MUI or Formik breaking changes in the future.

Comment: After couple of days with that. I think you might be right. Thanks! Now I need to figure out how to map those components.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As mentionned in comments, it may actually be a good idea to implement "wrapper" components, like they did in this samples from Formik or ReactFinalForm :

- https://github.com/stackworx/formik-material-ui/tree/master/src
- https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#material-ui-10

The idea is the same : implement custom "wrapper" components to wrap Material-UI components and map Formik or ReactFinalForm APIs props.

The advantages of this approach is to centralize in one place the mapping between the two frameworks, so that you do not repeat the mapping each time, and if one of the framework introduces breaking changes you just have to change those custom "wrapper" components.

Answer (score 31):

I don't think you need another library or even create your own wrapper, I think you need to tweek your code a bit.

One problem you have is that you don't pass an onChange function in the Material TextField so the form value of firstName is always null and so you always get the error, even if you have entered a name.
Try adding a name or id on your TextField and an onChange function like so:

```
<Field
    validateOnBlur
    validateOnChange
    name="firstName"
    render={({ field, form }) => (
    <TextField
        name={"firstName"}
        error={
            Boolean(form.errors.firstName && form.touched.firstName)
        }
        onChange={formikBag.handleChange}
        onBlur={formikBag.handleBlur}
        helperText={
            form.errors.firstName &&
            form.touched.firstName &&
            String(form.errors.firstName)
        }
    />
    )}
/>
```

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. The error doesn't show when the field is empty

Comment: The error appears but currently you have set up your validations to appear onSubmit. This means you need to press enter for it to appear. If you want them to appear also onChange and onBlur see my updated answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: You will find youself repeating the props mapping to Material-UI components props in every "Field" instances, that's the point of creating Material-UI wrappers for me, and it does have sense to centralize this mapping in custom components. Imagine one day where MUI or Formik has a breaking change in their API/Props. You just have to update one component !

Comment: You are right a wrapper component is a good idea. But I think the first thing to do here is make it work on a single field and then he can focus on building wrappers based on what he needs to build.

Comment: This is the place to go https://formik.org/docs/api/field#children

Answer (score 8):

You can try this: https://github.com/daixianceng/formik-material-fields

Installation:

```
npm install --save formik-material-fields
```

Usage:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Formik, Form } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { FormikTextField } from 'formik-material-fields';

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  username: Yup.string().required(),
});

const initialValues = {
  username: '',
};

class MyForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}
      >
        {({ isValid }) => (
          <Form autoComplete="off">
            <FormikTextField
              name="username"
              label="Username"
              margin="normal"
              fullWidth
            />
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer!! Thanks

Comment: For a backend guy that needed a quick and easy UI, this library is fantastic!

Answer (score 7):

Check out the formik docs for `<Field />` here: https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field

As an example you could use Material's OutlinedInput to style your input:

```
<Field as={OutlinedInput} />
```

If you need to pass more props to OutlinedInput, simply add them to Field and it will pass them on to OutlinedInput:

```
<Field as={OutlinedInput} color="primary" InputProps={{ startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start"><AccountCircle /></InputAdornment> }} />
```

Comment: Should be the the accepted answer. Note that Field will pass down any props down to OutlinedInput for example <Field label="Name" as={OutlinedInput} /> will render <OutlinedInput label="Name />

Answer (score 3):

You can use [setFieldValue](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--void) method ***useful for creating custom input change handlers***

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    name: "",
  }}
  onSubmit={(values: any) => console.log(values)}
>
  {({  handleSubmit, setFieldValue }) => (
    <Form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <TextField
        onChange={(event) => setFieldValue("name", event.target.value)} 
        type="text"
        label="Name"
      />
    </Form>
  )}
</Formik>
```

Answer (score 2):

To use **material-ui** and **formik**, you can use the variant from the **official formik documentation**:
https://formik.org/docs/examples/with-material-ui

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this library, which does the heavy-lifting for you and implements the wrapper code around Material-UI components (including `<TextField />`): https://github.com/stackworx/formik-material-ui.

Installation:

```
yarn add formik-material-ui
```

In your Formik form component, pass the `<TextField />` component as the component prop of the Formik `<Field />` component.

```
import { Formik, Field, Form } from 'formik';
import { TextField } from 'formik-material-ui';

<Field
  name="email"
  label="Email"
  type="email"
  component={TextField}
/>
```

Formik will continue to handle the validation as expected and will render the Material UI component and error message. There are additional details in the docs for other Mui input components and to aid with customization.